# According to style is it right to put a funcion like parameter when ending an aplication with sys.exit() in python?

Tags: python

I have seen a code written like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #...
    result = someFunction(someParameter)
    sys.exit(result)
```

and even like this, where you write the call of the function in the sys.exit() function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #...
    sys.exit(someFunction(someParameter))
```

Which is the most correct option according to style?

Comment: That's not an alternative, it is the same thing, just that in the second one you did not create any variable.

Comment: What if there is some code after all that (forget the `sys.exit()`) ? If you use a variable, its value is stored, what happen if you use the result of a function inline? is its returned value still in the stack after you had use of it?
do you have to call `gc.collect()` ? an answer about python's memory management would be great.

Comment: It's the same result, but not the same thing.. I wanted to know what was the best option according to style. Like freebie said, the most readable option is the correct, so the first.

Answer (score 3):

Both are equivalent, but I think you know this. If you are asking from a style perspective, I'd say you should always favour the option that is more readable. In this case, I think the first one is more readable.

Python uses snake_case by convention so you might consider also using that to define your variables and functions.

You might also want to change the name of the `result` variable to be more descriptive.

```
exit_status = some_function(some_parameter)
sys.exit(exit_status)
```

Hopefully, this was what you were after.

Edit: @AnttiHaapala made a good point that `succeeded` isn't the best variable name either as 0 is Falsy in Python but considered a pass as an exit code. I've renamed it to `exit_status`.

Comment: well, I wouldn't name the variable "succeeded" as `sys.exit` takes the exit code, which would be `0` for success, but in Python `0` is considered a *falsy* value.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Good point. What would you call it?

Comment: perhaps that `exit_status` or `exit_code`